# how to change scrollbar slider color in a theme

Tags: debian, xfce, theme, gtk3

Running Debian 11 and xfce, I'm trying to figure out how to change the default scrollbar slider colors, the dull grey just doesn't do it for me.

Edit: Ok, this works:

```
scrollbar
{
    -XfceTasklist-min-button-length: 3000; 
    /* Needed or else no buttons! */
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: true;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: true;
}
scrollbar slider { min-width: 20px; }
scrollbar button {padding: 6px}

/* dark green: pointer is not in the active window */
scrollbar slider:backdrop { background-color: #00aa00; }
scrollbar button:backdrop { color: #00aa00; }

/* green: pointer is in the active window but not on the slider/button */
scrollbar slider { background-color: #00ff00; } 
scrollbar button { color: #00ff00; }

/* dark red: pointer is hovering over slider/button, but mouse button not pressed */
scrollbar slider:hover { background-color: #aa0000; } 
scrollbar button:hover { color: #aa0000; }

/* red: slider/button is active */
scrollbar slider:hover:active { background-color: #ff0000; }
scrollbar button:active { color: #ff0000; }

/* slider maxed out, window active */
scrollbar button:disabled { color: white; }

/* slider maxed out, window inactive */
scrollbar button:backdrop:disabled { color: white; }

/* What is this? */
scrollbar button:checked { color: black; }
```

... any comments or improvements most welcome.

Comment: which theme are you using and which file you edited ( ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css)? How do you apply settings for firefox (widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar...)?